# Quando utilizar "texto pré-formatado" e ênfase em itálico?

Tags: suporte

Surgiu esta dúvida após uma edição feita [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35413/o-que-s%C3%A3o-views-em-sql-quais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-em-utilizar) questão que coloquei.

Eu, normalmente, utilizo a marcação de textos pré-formatados quando me refiro a expressões próprias de uma linguagem de programação ou de marcação. Após a edição feita (não vejo mal algum na edição, por acaso achei limpa) gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão para o uso das marcações?

**Nota:**

Observei que alguns termos foram colocados em *itálico* e gostaria de perceber o porquê.

Comment: Falta o link para a questão

Comment: Mas normalmente o **itálico** é usado para estrangeirismos como *stack* ou *overflow*.

Comment: talvez seja dup http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas

Comment: Editei @JorgeB. Perdão

Comment: Como eu tinha dito é como se convencionou o uso de estrangeirismos. E sim @bigown é duplicata.

Comment: Tem uma situação limite que nem eu sei bem quando usar o que. Quando uma palavra é algo que pertence à código (então normalmente usaria pré-formatado, mas naquele contexto ele não está agindo como código mas é uma palavra em inglês, aí deveria ser itálico. (Alias não sei se é pré-formatado ou pre-formatado atualmente, que falta tá fazendo o http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language)

Comment: Concordo contigo quanto ao uso do código/itálico. É pré-formatado @bigown

Comment: Pegando carona na discussão, muitas vezes eu uso itálico quando quero dar *ênfase* em alguma coisa (*emphasized text*... `<em>`...) - em vez do negrito, que é mais **gritante** (ainda que nem tão GRITANTE). Esse seria um uso aceitável, além dos estrangeirismos?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Claro. Nunca vi abuso em itálico, vi em negrito (acho que faço um pouco :) devia usar + itálico em alguns casos) e de pré-formatado.

Comment: @JorgeB. não sei se confio nesses portugueses que ainda não se acostumaram com as novas regras ortográficas :P Mas pode ser, o fato é que o corretor ortográfico não está reclamando de nenhum (pode ser falha dele ou está usando as regra antiga e nova simultaneamente).

Comment: @bigown facto e fato estão corretos por exemplo. Eu pessoalmente não gosto de fato, faz lembra os fatos (roupa)